# get the color for every category

Tags: python, seaborn, legend

I have the following chart
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpm4h.jpg)

I need to get the color for every category in the legend. for example I need to know what the color that is used for the twitter platform.
I retrieve the texts for the legend by using

```
legend=ax.get_legend()
  legend.texts
```

but still I need to know the color

Comment: I think you tackle the problem the wrong way around. You actually *set* the color of those points implicitely when producing the plot. So it would be best to get the color from the palette you use for plotting. How do you create that plot?

Comment: actually that the first thing come to my mind but I could not get the color from the palette since it's done implicitly  this the code to produce the plot :                               SInteractions_Graph = sns.swarmplot(x="KPI", y="value", hue="Platform", data=irisS)

Comment: is there way to return the default palette that is used produce the plot ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest the following: If you specify the palette and hue order to use for the plot you can use those to also directly return the color of the hue category in the plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : ["Category"] * 30,
                   "y" : np.random.rand(30),
                   "hue" : np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJKL"), size=30)})

hues = df["hue"].unique()
palette = sns.husl_palette(len(hues), l=0.7)

sns.swarmplot(x="x", y="y", hue="hue", palette=palette, hue_order=hues, data=df)
```

outputs

[image]

Then

```
# print the color of the letter 'B' in the plot
color = palette[list(hues).index("B")]
print(color)
```

gives you the RGB color

```
[0.21538975947324868, 0.7566005611127228, 0.3762755878794595]
```

or, for all colors

```
for hue, color in zip(hues, palette):
    print("The color of '{}' is: {}".format(hue, color))
```

outputs

```
The color of 'C' is: [0.9709009234187059, 0.5326413088101082, 0.6030946551014079]
The color of 'G' is: [0.9564746134064298, 0.5689330861555781, 0.21514455558380652]
The color of 'E' is: [0.7694979084301814, 0.6558708257601433, 0.21360096988729887]
The color of 'I' is: [0.5896986083607835, 0.7091177093811508, 0.21250650504472351]
The color of 'B' is: [0.21538975947324868, 0.7566005611127228, 0.3762755878794595]
The color of 'D' is: [0.22701819286983138, 0.7401655088143408, 0.632501836267289]
The color of 'L' is: [0.2350973175622082, 0.7278659021357948, 0.7570948140143763]
The color of 'J' is: [0.24712600818727698, 0.708085275229765, 0.9105299070653927]
The color of 'H' is: [0.6214187468312122, 0.6348139081106288, 0.9644867235044855]
The color of 'A' is: [0.874677664347576, 0.53077533058416, 0.9640932638014564]
The color of 'F' is: [0.9675513199127449, 0.5048915449454215, 0.8037781860187498]
```